# insertNode' on 'Range': Only one element on document allowed

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hii I am inserting a node in the loop but it's giving an error "insertNode' on 'Range': Only one element on document allowed.". I have two types of data one inside single div whole and on inside div, there are a lot of spans. So in the second type of data, it's giving an error.

Below code, I am using.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var x;
  var url = window.location.pathname;
  var urlid = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    
  $.ajax({
  type:'GET',
  url:'/check-words',
  data:{urlid:urlid},
  success:function(data){
   for (var x of data) 
   {
    var jsondata = x + '';
    var nameArr = jsondata.split(',');
    var a = nameArr[0];
    var b = nameArr[1];
    
    highlight($('.main-detail-content'), a, b);
   }
  }
 })
}); 


function highlight(element,st,en)
{
    range = document.createRange();
     
    dig(element,st,en,range,0);
    
    s.addRange(range);

    var ra = s.getRangeAt(0);  
    var newNode = document.createElement("em");
    newNode.appendChild(ra.extractContents());
    ra.insertNode(newNode);

    s.removeAllRanges();
   
}



function dig(el,start,end,range,pos)
{
    $(el).contents().each(function(i,e){
        if (e.nodeType==1){
            pos = pos+ e.innerHTML.length;
            
         // dig(e,start,end,range,pos);   
        }
        else
        {
            if (pos < start){
               if (pos +  e.length >= start){
                range.setStart(e, start - pos); 
               }
            }
            
            if (pos < end)
            {
               if (pos + e.length >= end)
               {
                range.setEnd(e, end - pos);
                return false;
               }
            }            
            
            pos = pos+e.length;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: My advice to you would be to reduce the amount of code you posted to the minimum required to reproduce the issue (plus, 80% of the time when I do that I find the solution myself). And if possible, use the executable code snippet function provided by stack overflow so we can see immediately what is happening.

Comment: Ok Positions I am getting from the database. dig() function is calculating range and the highlight function is inserting em tag on matching words. thats all what i can inform you. Thanks for the help.